# Sed : how to print quotes in the middle of a string and at the end

Tags: windows, sed, awk, quotes

I am working on Windows, but Unix example will help me. 
I am trying to have this type of input

```
    \\server\share
```

Output

```
    \\server\"share"
```

I can add quotes at the end if I do it by sed "$s/.""/"

But I don't know how to do it after the last slash.

Help appreciated

Comment: Wrong code, sed "$s/.$""/" to add last quotes at the end

Comment: echo \\server\share | sed -e "s;\(.*\\\);\1"";" | sed "$s/.$/""/"

Answer (score 1):

```
\\server\/"share/"
```

Not sure if that's what you are looking for

Comment: did u try : `sed 's/\(.*\)\r/"\1"/g'`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(.*\\)(.*)/\1"\2"/' file
```

Which uses greed to locate the last `\` and then enclose the remaining string with double-quotes.

Or:

```
sed -r 's/[^\\]+$/"&"/' file
```

Which works backwards through the line until it finds a `\`.